# How would one show two groups aren't isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

I have to show that $U(n)$ - the group of unitary matrices is not isomorphic to $SU(n) \times S^1$. I have seen answer on here before but that included something called a 'short exact sequence' I haven come across what this means yet so I'm assuming there must be a simpler way to show this?

Comment: To show something false, finding a counterexample is usually easiest. What that must be the same for two groups that are isomorphic can you can show is not the same between $U(n)$ and $SU(n)\times S^1$?

Comment: What's the centre of $\text{SU}(n)$?

Comment: At first |I thought the size of the group but that didnt work out

Comment: @Drevvvy: What is $S^1$?

Comment: @Tortoise it is the group of complex numbers of length 1

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown the center of $SU(n)$ is just $aI$, where $a$ is an nth root of unity